# Understanding the following React + TypeScript installation command

Tags: reactjs, typescript, installation, types

I am trying to create a React + TypeScript demo project from scratch. However, I do not fully understand the following installation command. In particular, I do not quite understand what `@types` is doing here. How can I understand it?

```
npm install react react-dom typescript @types/react @types/react-dom --save
```

Also, I think some time ago npm made `--save` the default option, so it should not be necessary here. Is that correct?

Comment: Typescript is a wrapper over JS that adds static typing feature to JS. However, React is a library and typescript's default implementation does not include such modules. Hence, you need to specify params what you need to install. Suggestion, react created **[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/)** to do basic config and boilerplate stuff.

Comment: Cool. That sounds great. Also, just FYI, I am aware of the CRA. However, I am trying to create a simple project without it. Thx.

Comment: Hi Grateful. Please try to stick to technical writing here. Remember that Stack Overflow questions and their answers are like Wikipedia or documentation - community-curated writing for the benefit of a large future audience. There are several discussions and guidelines on Meta regarding chatty or pleading material in questions - I can get you some links on request.

Comment: In the meantime, I sometimes give this advice on Stack Overflow: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: A related theme from me on _Meta_: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@types` packages contain type definitions for TypeScript. It's an [organisation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Etypes) which contains definitions for many libraries. These definitions allow the library to be consumed from within other code bases, as it describes what the API is and what the types used are, thus enabling the use of the TypeScript compiler to check if the correct functions are called with the correct parameters.

These type definitions can also be created for libraries written in plain JavaScript. This again allows them to effectively be used from TypeScript codebases. Many such definitions are produced by the [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org/) project.

Comment: So, in essence, these type definitions allow TypeScript to be able to recognise external libraries like jQuery?

Comment: That's exactly it. jQuery is writtein in plain JS so if you try to do `$(".someclass").addClass("other")` TypeScript won't know if that's correct nor would it know what it will return. However the type definitions correct that and TS will stop you from calling non-existing methods, passing the wrong arguments, or using the result incorrectly.